# Как устранить ошибку GET http://vue-app/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

Прошу помощи, мучаюсь с этим уже какой день.
Пожалуй, нужно расписать конкретно, что я сделала. Я создала новый проект в папке domains в Open Server, загрузила laravel (команда: laravel new), далее проделала команды (composer require laravel/ui, php artisan ui vue, npm install, npm run dev). В папке /public/js создала файл main.js. Его содержимое:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  mounted() {
    axios.get('/skills').then(response => console.log(response));
  }
});
```

Далее web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('skills', function() {
  return ['Laravel', 'Vue', 'PHP', 'JavaScript', 'Tooling'];
});
```

И welcome.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">

        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>
        <script src = "/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Открыла в браузере с помощью Open Server и увидела ошибку: Как устранить ошибку GET http://vue-app/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, отобразите код текстом, т.к его легче читать и легко копировать. Чтобы внести правки в вопрос, используйте кнопку "Править".

Comment: main.js где у Вас лежит( в какой папке)?

Comment: @h4cktivist, спасибо за замечание, внесла поправки

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy вот путь: C:\Users\OpenServer\domains\vue-app\public\js\main.js

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, а на последнем скрине четко видно, что этот файл ищется по в корне сайта, т.е. должно быть что то похожее "/public/js/main.js", а не "/js/main.js" .

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, изменила `<script src = "/public/js/main.js"></script>`, в devtools появились такие ошибки:
1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2) Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at e.exports (spread.js:25)
at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange
3) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Что это может значить? Всё ещё не понимаю, как решить проблему

Comment: new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  mounted() {
     axios.get('/skills').then(response => console.log(response)); // Заккоментируйте запрос аксиоса
  }
});

Comment: Либо просто удалите вот эти строчки
mounted() {
    axios.get('/skills').then(response => console.log(response));
  }

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, 3 новых ошибки, с большой степенью вероятности, говорят о том, что у вас заработал файл со скриптами main.js и, т.к. там есть аякс запрос от аксиоса, он не может найти вот этот путь '/skills' . По этому я и предложил выше - либо закомментировать этот запрос, либо вообще его убрать.

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, Почему он не может найти путь '/skills'?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, Я понимаю, что можно убрать запрос, но это же не решение проблемы. Упражнение в том и заключается, чтобы научиться этому.

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, а Вы его создавали этот путь? Консольная команда 
php artisan route:list - что показывает

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy +--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api        |
|        |          |          |      |         | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | skills   |      | Closure | web        |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, извините, не смогла прикрепить скрин. Но я создавала путь в файле web.php - его код изначально прикреплён

Comment: @ТаняМальцева, просто пример - что будет если в браузере вызовете vue.app/skills ?

Comment: @AlexZelenskiy, The content of the page cannot be displayed

Comment: По сути - это и есть ваш гет запрос. Я с опенсервером полгода не работал, но точно помню, что его нужно немного донастраивать либо возится с путями. Минут через 15 попробую более предметно сказать(просто посмотрю что и как в нем называется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробуем решить вашу проблему

1. Настраиваем OpenServer
   Идем в настройки OpenServer -> вкладка домены и добавляем

- доменное имя **vueapp**
- папка домена **vueapp/public**

Важно  **добавить**, а потом **сохранить** (сервер перезапустится и не нужно будет больше прописывать public при вызовах)

2. Возвращаем в "/js/main.js" в welcome.blade.php (путь должен нормально перенаправлятся)
3. Файл путей **web.php**

Ответ было бы правильнее через респонс отправлять, сорри за тавталогию

```
Route::get('/skills', function() { 

return response()->json(
[ 'one', 'two','three'],
 200); 
 });
```

Должно заработать

Comment: большое-большое спасибо Вам! Всё заработало, когда ответ был отправлен через response.